# Not sure why regex is not working

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following regex:

```
a=/item\/([0-9]+)\)/.match("item/123) and also item/245)")
```

I'm trying to pull out the item ids of all the links in a string, something like:

```
 [123,245]
```

but it returns

```
<MatchData "item/123)" 1:"123">
```

(ie only the first). How can I make it return both ids (either as part of two MatchData or via some other method)? I think I need to specify greedy but not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do as below using [`scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-scan):

> If the pattern contains no groups, each individual result consists of the matched string, $&. *If the pattern contains groups, each individual result is itself an array containing one entry per group.*

```
"item/123) and also item/245)".scan(/item\/([0-9]+)\)/).flatten
# => ["123", "245"]
s = "item/123) and also item/245)"
s.scan(/item\/([0-9]+)\)/).flatten.map(&:to_i) # to get them as integers
# => [123, 245]
```

As you have created single capturing group, thus got only one result :

```
a = /item\/([0-9]+)\)/.match("item/123) and also item/245)")
a.captures # => ["123"]
```

Look also the method [`captures`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/MatchData.html#method-i-captures) .

Comment: is there a way to do multi-capturing? have to wait a few before accepting

Comment: @timpone Go with this `scan` method only. If you need to capture 10 items, without scan, you need to write 10 `(..) (...)..` so on.

Answer (score 4):

Without capturing unnecessary things:

```
"item/123) and also item/245)".scan(%r{(?<=item/)\d+(?=\))})
# => ["123", "245"]
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you want are the ids, and there are no other numbers in the text, you can greatly simplify your pattern:

```
"item/123) and also item/245)".scan(/\d+/) # => ["123", "245"]
```

Or, if you want integers instead of strings:

```
"item/123) and also item/245)".scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i) # => [123, 245]
```

If you have some numbers you want to avoid, you can test for "index/" followed by a number, using the positive look-behind that @sawa suggested, or use something along these lines:

```
"item/123) and also item/245)".scan(%r[item/\d+]).map{ |s| s[/\d+/] } # => ["123", "245"]
```

Or:

```
"item/123) and also item/245)".scan(%r[item/\d+]).map{ |s| s[/\d+/].to_i } # => [123, 245]
```

Breaking that down so you can see what's happening:

```
"item/123) and also item/245)".scan(%r[item/\d+]) # => ["item/123", "item/245"]
"item/123"[/\d+/] # => "123"
```

Personally, I like @sawa's answer, because it's clean and simple and will only find numbers following "item/" and avoids needing capture groups which force a subsequent `flatten`. I just wanted to show how to do it using a simpler pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `scan` method for this.

```
a = "item/123) and also item/245)".scan(/item\/([0-9]+)\)/)
```

Which returns:

```
[["123"], ["245"]]
```

Comment: Myself first... by 15 seconds :-)

Comment: Be careful with the capture in your pattern. The OP wanted a flat array, and the capture will cause `scan` to return an array of arrays.